# HTML input number type specify first value

Tags: html, angular

I have an HTML input that indicates a year as so:

```
<input type="number" name="year" placeholder="Year" [max]="presentYear" min="1950">
```

The input is not required, so by default I simply want the placeholder "Year" to be present. However, as soon as the user clicks on the up or down arrows of the input field, I want the `max` value to be shown as default, in this case the present year (2018). However, the minimum number is shown instead. This makes no sense for this situation, since the user would have to scroll through 68 years to get to the most common use case.

Is there any way to specify the default "first value" of a number type input field? If it helps answer the question, I'm using Angular 5 for this project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set `min` to the same value as `max` initially, and change it for 1950 after the input value has been changed, with the help of `ngModel` and `ngModelChange`. The first click on the spinner button will set the current year as the initial value, and the modified `min` value will allow to change it afterwards.

```
<input type="number" name="year" placeholder="Year" 
    [(ngModel)]="year" (ngModelChange)="setMinYear($event)" 
    [max]="presentYear" [min]="minYear">
```

```
export class AppComponent {
  presentYear = this.getCurrentYear();
  minYear = this.getCurrentYear();
  year: number;

  private getCurrentYear(): number {
    return new Date().getUTCFullYear();
  }

  public setMinYear(value: number) {
    const firstYear = 1950;
    if (value >= firstYear) {
      this.minYear = firstYear;
    } else {
      this.minYear = this.presentYear;
    }
  }
}
```

The code can be tested in [**this stackblitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/template-driven-form-2-gcrcf1).

Comment: This only works the first time around. If the user wipes out the value then uses the arrow again, we're back to square one. However, it got me far along enough to figure out how to solve this, so I'll mark it as accepted.

Comment: I changed the `ngModelChange` event handler to reset the `min` value if the field is cleared.

Answer (score 0):

in JS:

```
dateObj: Date = new Date();
year: number = dateObj.getUTCFullYear();
yearModel: number = year;
```

in HTML

Bind property to your input control , as given in below code it will do for you

```
<input type="number" name="year" 
  placeholder="Year" 
  [(ngModel)] = "yearModel"
  [max]="year"
  min="1950">
```

A separate Model prevents the value to go over the current year